# Downscale a4 to B5, prepare with pdfpages on a3 with crop marks

Tags: pdfpages, crop

I'm preparing a book for printing. The book was written and finely tuned to A4 but I want to try downscaling it to B5 (simply changing the `geometry` in the main document reeks havoc with my layout.). However, i'm stuck when using `pdfpages` on how to achieve both 1) downsizing and 2) printing it on in the center of a A3 paper *and* 3) having crop marks for the bookbinder.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=16,landscape]{book.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

First i did the downscale:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{article} % Downscales my A4 paper to B5
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{bookA4.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Then i compiled it with crop marks:

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{article}
\usepackage[info,axes,cam,center,a3,pdflatex]{crop}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,signature=16,landscape]{bookB5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Looks rather good.

[image]